# How to store image in big size in local?

Tags: iphone, image

I am storing an image locally but my image is store in small size. i want to store this image in orignal size how can i do this ?

my code for store image is like this ..

```
NSString *myurl = [[NSString alloc]init];
myurl =[data valueForKey:@"large_image"];

NSData *mydata = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myurl]] retain];
UIImage *myimage = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata] retain];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png",documentsDirectory];   

NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:Imagename];
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

this is stored image
[image]

and this is orignal image

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by big vs small? When you view it again? 

You seem to be saving the data correctly. Maybe you are scaling/zooming the image when you're viewing it

Comment: i think now u can understand big and small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am doing wrong in code. this is the reason. why this happend.

may be it is because of leak ok knowledge that time. :)

other wise all things is correct only.